# Macos Yosemite with ulimit unlimited

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, mamp, osx-yosemite

How do I run apache2 on Macos Yosemite. I am getting 2 errors:

Error #1

```
+ ulimit -S -n unlimited
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl: line 70: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

Error #2

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash ulimit on Yosemite returns "ulimited" for the command "ulimit -H -n" this value cannot be set.

Check that a value for max files is set in /etc/sysctl.conf. I have (from postgres):

```
kern.maxfiles=524289
kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
```

With a default (ulimit -n) of 2560. See http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/ for more details.

Change apachectl from:

```
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n `ulimit -H -n`
```

to:

```
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n `sysctl -A | grep kern.maxfiles: | awk '{ print $2}' `"
```

Problem 2:  Rename envvars (MAMP specific)

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
mv envvars _envvars
```

As per: http://www.gladdy.uk/blog/2014/08/05/mamp-pro-on-yosemite-beta-5/